# updating browser address field correctly on `pushstate`

Tags: browser-history, pushstate

I am loading data in the web page via ajax, and using pushstate and popstate trickery to change the browser address field. The problem is that my ajax URLs are like so

```
2011/07/25/foo.txt 
2011/07/26/bar.txt 
2011/07/27/baz.txt
```

So, the first time the web page loads, the browser address field is `http://webserver/`. On the first ajax load, it becomes `http://webserver/2011/07/25/foo.txt`. On the second ajax load it becomes `http://webserver/2011/07/25/2011/07/26/bar.txt`. On the third ajax load the browser URL field becomes `http://webserver/2011/07/25/2011/07/26/2011/07/27/baz.txt`. In other words, only the last fragment of the address field (split on '/') gets replaced.

How can I replace the entire address field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a leading `/` to the pushed path.